# Remote debugging .net core 2.0 console app over ssh

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, remote-debugging, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a .net core 2.0 console app on windows 10 but I want to debug it on a remote linux server running debian 9.

I found this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/01/26/debugging-net-core-on-unix-over-ssh/

but where I get stuck is selecting the SSH connection.  My remote server has authentication and if I enter the `user@ip:port` it doesn't find anything.

[image]

I found some mention of using SSH tunnelling but as there is no dotnet process listening on the server (it's installed but it doesn't have any listening service running I can see) I am unsure exactly what port I'm meant to be tunnelling or even which direction to tunnel it.

What do I need to do to get my SSH connection visible in the debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried this and I found that the **Find..** button doesn't do anything either.

First you enable SSH connections in your Linux host (in my case, Ubuntu, I had to run `sudo ufw allow ssh`). Test things out by opening cmd on Windows and doing `ssh user@host`.

Then, on Visual Studio, in the SSH attach to process window, make sure you hit "refresh" and check the "show processes from all users" box. You should see the "dotnet" process running.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**: you should be prompted for the remote host's password at some point. Here's the dialog shown when I changed the password on the remote host and then attempted to debug.

[image]

Comment: is your linux host on your local network and not requiring authentication?  Mine is remote and requires authentication

Comment: My host is local but it requires authentication.

Comment: where are you specifying authentication settings for linux host on dev box?

Comment: It asked for them the 1st time I tried to refresh the processed I think. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ahh intersting, I do not get this dialogue appear

Comment: I think it is because I am not using port 22.  I specify like user@ip:port.  Do you know if that syntax is correct?